# Ubuntu 17.04 to Kubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu

I'm upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to Kubuntu 17.10. I've read many related questions but I still don't know if I should:

a) Install Kubuntu

b) Upgrade

Or the other way around. Does it make any difference?

Comment: It does not make any difference for most users. Both methods are supported and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to:

a) Upgrade

b) Install Kubuntu

It worked fine. I still don't know if the result is different or not.